# I want to pass an input value to the where clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, psycopg2

I have a variable named create_project, which is a text box. I will have to enter a value into that text box. With the assigned value create_project.the value, I will have to create a schema. Before creating the schema with that value, I need to check if there is any schema with the same name in the table. for that, I am writing the below query

```
select count(*) from pg_namespace where nspname= '$create_project.value'
```

but the above query returns nothing. $create_project.value is a variable with one assigned value named project.

If I write the same query as below, it returns 1 row.

```
select count(*) from pg_namespace where nspname= 'project'
```

I see the below error message:

**(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "project1" does not exist
LINE 1: ...count(*) from pg_namespace where "nspname"= ''''||project1||...**

I am pretty new to Postgres and never worked before. So, Can someone please help me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why does your program has to create new schema? Because that means that the database role that you use for this program, must have the permissions to create a schema. And probably also tables and other database objects. This is something I would never do because of security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no need to check this table.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS project;
```

will check it for you. Second, probably you run your SQL outside of the Postgres, removing quotes will work correctly. Because with single quotes postgres takes it as is.

```
select count(*) from pg_namespace where nspname= $create_project.value
```

or

```
select count(*) from pg_namespace where nspname= ''''||$create_project.value||'''';
```

Comment: I already tried with the above code, but it is not working. I am running these queries in the Jupyter notebook; that might be the issue. I see the below error when I run the above queries. **(psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "project1" does not exist
LINE 1: ...count(*) from pg_namespace where "nspname"= ''''||project1||...**